# Is Exception Handling in Java a form of testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Simply as the title says: Is Exception handling in java a form of testing? Which category of testing will it come under?

Comment: No, it is not a form of testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's a way to manage errors that occur during program execution. It is not a form of unit testing.

Comment: Testing is used to find and detect errors, exception handling throws exceptions often giving you and indication how and why it happened, allowing developers to approach that place where it was thrown and correct appropriately. Isnt this testing?

Comment: @Hoody No. Testing is for detecting whether code generates errors. Exception handling is for telling code what to do when errors occur.